# nodejs client for google resource calendar APIs

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-nodejs-client

I am working on a functionality where I need to fetch information about the meeting rooms which are treated as resource calendars. I am using [googleapis node js client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) for other calendar related APIs, for e.g. events list, insert. I'm not able to find any methods in googleapis library to fetch data from resource calendar which is part of google admin SDK. Is there a NodeJS client for resource calendar API? Or any other way to call those APIs?

Comment: To start with, you can use the code provided in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs) to have a simple Node.js command-line application that makes requests to the Google Calendar API. For the method you need, you can use the code provided in [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples).

Comment: I already have coded an application using NodeJS which provides me all the calendar events, can create events. What I am struggling with is the calendar resource APIs. Calendar resources are used to store meeting rooms etc. And I can not find api client for that particular functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm doing the same kind of app and also blocked on the resources part.

It seems like all the resources are accessible through the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/nodejs).

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';

var service = google.admin('directory_v1');
service.resources.calendars.list();
```

You need to activate the Admin SDK in de Google Developper Console.

And I suppose to connect with an admin account.

It's stupid because as a regular user you can see the resources like rooms for calendar.